# How to finish a broken data upload to the production Google App Engine server?

Tags: google-app-engine, upload, google-cloud-datastore, bulk

I was [uploading the data to App Engine](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Uploading_the_Data_to_App_Engine) (not dev server) through loader class and remote api, and I hit the quota in the middle of a CSV file. Based on logs and progress sqllite db, how can I select remaining portion of data to be uploaded?

Going through tens of records to determine which was and which was not transfered, is not appealing task, so I look for some way to limit the number of record I need to check.

Here's relevant (IMO) log portion, how to interpret work item numbers?

```
[DEBUG    2010-03-30 03:22:51,757 bulkloader.py] [Thread-2] [1041-1050] Transferred 10 entities in 3.9 seconds
[DEBUG    2010-03-30 03:22:51,757 adaptive_thread_pool.py] [Thread-2] Got work item [1071-1080]
<cut>
[DEBUG    2010-03-30 03:23:09,194 bulkloader.py] [Thread-1] [1141-1150] Transferred 10 entities in 4.6 seconds
[DEBUG    2010-03-30 03:23:09,194 adaptive_thread_pool.py] [Thread-1] Got work item [1161-1170]
<cut>
[DEBUG    2010-03-30 03:23:09,226 bulkloader.py] [Thread-3] [1151-1160] Transferred 10 entities in 4.2 seconds
[DEBUG    2010-03-30 03:23:09,226 adaptive_thread_pool.py] [Thread-3] Got work item [1171-1180]
[ERROR    2010-03-30 03:23:10,174 bulkloader.py] Retrying on non-fatal HTTP error: 503 Service Unavailable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [resume](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Uploading_the_Data_to_App_Engine) a broken upload:

> If the transfer is interrupted, you
>   can resume the transfer from where it
>   left off using the --db_filename=...
>   argument. The value is the name of the
>   progress file created by the tool,
>   which is either a name you provided
>   with the --db_filename argument when
>   you started the transfer, or a default
>   name that includes a timestamp. This
>   assumes you have sqlite3 installed,
>   and did not disable the progress file
>   with --db_filename=skip.