# Cannot delete GAE file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to remove a file after a broken upload using

```
final FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
fileService.delete(file);
```

But I get:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: File \/blobstore\/writable:AD8BvukH[...]qau-Bb7AD does not have a finalized name
```

When I try to finalize the file with

```
FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, true);
writeChannel.closeFinally();
```

then openWriteChannel() fails with

```
com.google.appengine.api.files.FinalizationException
[...]
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 101:
```

What does ApplicationError 101 mean?
How can I properly delete the file?

Comment: It could have become `orphaned`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like others have reported this problem and, although it was addressed, there could still be a problem with broken files.

> **Sep 11, 2013 at 1:14 am**
>
> We have now fixed this issue from reoccurring in future. However,
>   there are some blobs created in the past that still give errors. We
>   are working on a fix for these blobs.
>
> John Lowry On behalf of the App Engine team

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-appengine/138xrawqw0/broken-blobstore-files-what-to-do

### `UnsupportedOperationException`

For the first error, [the documentation states](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileService):

> `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` - if a file's type is not supported by delete or file does not have a finalized name.

It could be that the file is already finalized, and you can't delete it for some other reason.

### `ApplicationError: 101`

I think the second error refers to a not found exception.

```
FinalizationError: ApplicationError: 101 Blobkey not found.
```

This may clarify the issue for you.

> You only use finalize if you create a file and write to it. But you
>   cannot write to a file, after it has been finalized. To update a file
>   in the blobstore, you always have to create a new one. And when you
>   read a file, you do not have to finalize it. To read a file you have
>   to use a blobreader. See:
>   https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/12855653/1085891

### Fixing the Broken Upload

You could [resume the upload](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Python_Uploading_the_data_to_App_Engine).

> If the transfer is interrupted, you can resume the transfer from where it left off using the `--db_filename=...` argument.

via [How to finish a broken data upload to the production Google App Engine server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547248/how-to-finish-a-broken-data-upload-to-the-production-google-app-engine-server)

#### Additional Solutions / Information:

- [Cannot delete entity with broken id from datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367030/cannot-delete-entity-with-broken-id-from-datastore)
- [Handle Form Failure when uploading to Appengine Blobstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272827/handle-form-failure-when-uploading-to-appengine-blobstore)
- [Issue 4744: Java dev server fails at deleting blobs.](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4744)

Comment: Thanks for the references. Unfortunately, they didn't really help.

Comment: @Michael so you are still unable to remove orphaned files? I'm seeing many other question and answers on SO regarding this issue: https://www.google.com/search?q=google+app+engine+orphaned